# Passing back value from Browse-Child VM chain to caller

Tags: mvvmcross

- MVVMCross
- Windows Store
- Android

I have a VM that browses a hierarchy (BrowseVm) and supports forward navigation via

```
 ShowViewModel<LeafDetailVM>
```

to a  leaf detail ViewModel (LeafDetailVM).

When the user is on the LeafDetail View they should be able to say "I want this one" and they will be returned to the View that initiated BrowseVm.

I cannot simply Forward Navigate to the Initiator because that would leave me with an invalid back stack. I cannot have the BrowseVM view as a NoHistory page as I need it be in the back stack to support going back from the LeafDetail view.

My plan is to have the initiator start BrowseVm with a GUID. BrowseVm will pass that GUID onto LeafDetailVM.

In the "I want this one" command I will raise a Message, containing the GUID, that both BrowseVM and the initiator are subscribed to. Then I will close LeafDetailVM.

When BrowseVM receives the notification of the message it will compare the GUID and if it matches it will close itself.

When the initiator receives the notification it will deal with the now chosen data.

Does this make sense? Have I missed a much simpler way of doing this?

This is similar to [How to pass a parameter from a viewmodel to its parent viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196356/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-a-viewmodel-to-its-parent-viewmodel) but that does not deal with the back stack.

Thanks

Comment: Is this of any use - http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/11/returning-results-from-view-models-in-mvvmcross/ ?

Comment: The problem i found was that I was ending up with the both Browse and the Detail activity open. Trying to shut both of those immediately, once a selction was made, was a problem. This was down to what Top Most Activity was equal to. I have come to the conclusion that my browse and detail UI should be done using Fragments(Android) and UserControls(Windows). Once I have done this I will update this question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try stop mentally coupling how the views work on a platform to the view-models.

With the custom presenter mechanism in MvvmCross, in the app (platform specific code) you can handle navigation to a certain view-model in different ways, including closing views, modify backstack, etc.
You can interpret navigation to a view-model in whatever way you want \ need.

You can for example pass from view-model some parameters in the ShowViewModel request which the view-presenter (IMvxViewPresenter) can interpret in different ways in the Show() to display a view-model.

In your case, you can actually navigate to initiator VM passing the selected info. In the view presenter, you can modify the backstack in the way you need.
On Android, make sure you read and know about all LaunchMode flags, for example LaunchMode.SingleTask which allows you bring the initiator activity to front without creating a new one.

It's not clear to me, is BrowseVm a parent view-model to the LeafDetailVM?
More info would be needed to understand exactly your scenario.

Comment: I already have a CustomPresenter and use that to support signing out and showing the Login Page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524972/android-activity-is-not-displayed-after-previously-shown-with-activityflags-newt. However that did not feel like the right solution as that was really used when I wanted to clear everything from the back stack not simply go back a steps. I also did not want to go to a fresh instance of the Initiating VM. I will however take a another look at the Android Flags. I will add some more info on BrowseVM

Comment: "You can interpret navigation to a view-model in whatever way you want \ need" I've never felt the ActivityFlags have ever been so freindly as to let me do whatever I wanted :-)

Comment: "I suggest you try stop mentally coupling how the views work on a platform to the view-models." I thing this approach completely decoupled from the platforms. I am simply trying to get Close called on two ViewModels leaving me at the previous one